# UI will not be updated after LiveData data is changed

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-jetpack

Here is my code:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
    val viewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(this)[HomeViewModel::class.java]
    }

    private lateinit var adapter: ArticleListAdapter

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        return root
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        rv_home.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
        adapter = ArticleListAdapter(viewModel.articleList)
        rv_home.adapter = adapter
        viewModel.getHomeArticle(0)


        viewModel.articleLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { result ->
            val HomePages = result.getOrNull()
            viewModel.articleList = HomePages
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })
    }

}
```

```
class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var articleList: HomeArticleBean? = null
    private val observerArticleLiveData = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    val articleLiveData = Transformations.switchMap(observerArticleLiveData) { page ->
        Repository.getHomeArticles(page)
    }

    fun getHomeArticle(page: Int) {
        observerArticleLiveData.value = page
    }
}
```

When I call getHomeArticle() from HomeFragment,the program should execute

```
Repository.getHomeArticles(page)
```

But after Dubug I found this line of code would not be executed.
This caused my articleLiveData observation in HomeFragment to be invalid, thus preventing me from updating the UI. I'm new to Jetpack so I don't know why this is happening, my code was written after someone else's code and I had no problems running his code, I looked carefully to see if there were differences between my code and his but didn't find any. I am searching for a long time on the net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas on how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with your use of `viewModel.articleList`:

```
   adapter = ArticleListAdapter(viewModel.articleList)
```

This creates your adapter and ties its data to the list currently stored at `viewModel.articleList` (which, for some reason, isn't in your `HomeViewModel` code?)

```
   viewModel.articleList = HomePages
```

This line completely throws away the list currently stored at `viewModel.articleList` and re-assigns the variable to store a completely new list. Your adapter knows nothing about this new list - it still has a reference to the old list.

Therefore you have a couple of choices:

1. Have your `ArticleListAdapter` have a `setData` method that takes the new list. That `setData` would update the list the `ArcticleListAdapter` is keeping track of (and, as a benefit, it could also internally call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, making it is always called.
2. Update the `viewModel.articleList` with new entries, rather than replace the whole list, thus ensuring that the list that `ArticleListAdapter` is using has your updated data:

```
viewModel.articleLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { result ->
    val HomePages = result.getOrNull()
    viewModel.articleList.clear()
    if (HomePages != null) {
        viewModel.articleList.addAll(HomePages)
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
})
```

3. Make your `ArticleListAdapter` extend [`ListAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter). This class handles tracking the list of data for you and gives you a simple `submitList` method which you'd call from your `observe` method. As a side benefit, it uses [`DiffUtil`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil) which is **way** more efficient than `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: The problem remains unresolved. And in my `Repository.getHomeArticles(page)` I have this line of code `Log.d(TAG, "getHomeArticles: Start requesting data")`. I checked Logcat and I can't find this line of log. It shows that `Repository.getHomeArticles(page)` is not executed. Therefore the data is not requested from the server.